# How to get the square of this expression?

Tags: vector-analysis, divergence-operator

I would like to open brackets of the following expression:

$$(\nabla+\textbf{A})^2$$ where $\textbf{A}=(2r^2,0,r sin(\theta))$.

I do: $(\nabla+\textbf{A})^2=\Delta+(\nabla\textbf{A})+(\textbf{A}\nabla)+A^2$

The expression $(\nabla\textbf{A})$ is divergence of vector $A$ and it is simplified to $8r$, but how to simplify expression $(\textbf{A}\nabla)$?

Help me please with this task

Comment: What does $\nabla+A$ actually _mean_?

Comment: @Parcly Taxel, $\nabla$ is operator nabla, it's a factor in momentum operator in quantum mechanics

Comment: $\Delta$ is the Nabla-Operator and A is the given vector field. So the sum of these two is nothing special, it is just the sum of these. The nabla operator can be written as $\partial_i$. It is a vector that contains the partial derivative for every koordinate. It has a vast use in Physics and not just quantuum mechanics.

Comment: The problem is that $\nabla$ needs to act on _something_ to be meaningful, since it is an operator. It can't just be added to other vectors nilly-willy.

Answer (score 2):

In cartesian coordinates, the expression you are looking for is $A_i\partial_i$. It represents an derivation in the "direction" of the vector field A. There is not much more you can do to it until you apply this new opperator onto something.